# Saving HTML form XML with user input values to javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, save

Currently right now I have a form rendering from a database from JSON.
What I want to do is store the Form html with the input values into a javascript variable.
Is there anyway that this would be possible?

Here would be a simple example..

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<button 
</form>
```

So the user would input the word "test". I then would want to store the following

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" value="test">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<button 
</form>
```

Would there be a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually build the string one piece at a time like this based on your form:

```
<form>  
  <input id="input1" type="text">
  <input id="input2" type="text">
  <input id="input3" type="text">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $("#submit").click(function(){
   var inputval1 = $("#input1").val();
   var inputval2 = $("#input2").val();
   var inputval3 = $("#input3").val();
     var value = '<form><input id="input1" type="text" value="'+inputval1+'" >';
         value += '<input id="input2" type="text" value="'+inputval2+'" >';
         value += '<input id="input3" type="text" value="'+inputval3+'" >';
         value += '<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">';
         value += '</form>';
     alert(value);  
   })  

});
```

**Fiddle:**  https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/eusrhy47/21/

Comment: Sorry this isnt what I am looking for, probably my explenation, I dont want to just save the value, I want to store the html that displays the form as a string so "<form> <input type="text" value="test"><input type="submit" value="submit"></form>" all in a string

Comment: Is there a way for the input value to update however? Here is the result I get currently <form method="post">
<input type="text" value="">
<button id="submit"> submit </button>
</form> The value input is empty

Comment: unfortunately the forms are created from a form builder, so each form could be different, so having a pre set amount of form fields with specific ID's wont work, I appreciate your help though and what you have provided is definitely something I can work upon to my solution

Comment: Oh I see. Glad I could help in some way, be it small or not. Good luck!